# Model change does not force ng-show to change visibility

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a fragment of my view that just shows a loading indicator.

Html:

```
<span class="app-loading-container">
    <span class="app-loading-animation" ng-show="loading"></span>
</span>
```

When I load the page the span shows, but when I call my refresh method nothing changes, yet I see that the loading variable is changing but the span is not showing. Is there something I missed to trigger the span to show?

Controller:

```
app.controller('SavedSearchesCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$window', 'lookupService', 'savedSearchesService', 
    function($scope, $filter, $window, lookupService, savedSearchesService) {


    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.alerts = [];



    function getSavedSearches() {
        savedSearchesService.getSavedSearches()
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.items = data;
                $scope.search();
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                $scope.alerts.push({ type: 'error', msg: 'Unable to load saved searches data: ' + error.message });
            });
            $scope.loading = false;
    }

    $scope.refreshClick = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        savedSearchesService.refreshSavedSearches()
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.items = data;
                $scope.search();
                $scope.alerts.push({ type: 'success', msg: 'Successfully refreshed saved searches data.'}); 
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                $scope.alerts.push({ type: 'error', msg: 'Unable to refresh saved searches data: ' + error.message });
            });
            $scope.loading = false;
    };

    $scope.deleteClick = function(id) {
        if (confirm("Delete this search? There's no undo...")) {
            savedSearchesService.deleteSavedSearch(id)
                .success(function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
                        var savedSearch = $scope.items[i];
                        if (savedSearch.SavedSearchKey === id) {
                            $scope.items.splice(i, 1);
                            $scope.search();
                            $scope.alerts.push({ msg: "Deleted saved search! Refreshing list." });
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.alerts.push({ type: 'error', msg: 'Unable to delete saved search: ' + error.message });     
                });
        }
    };

    getSavedSearches();
}]);
```

I ripped out parts of the controller for this post so this may not work if pasted your IDE.

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since HTTP requests are asynchronous, you're essentially saying:

```
$scope.refreshClick = function () {
    $scope.loading = true;
    // do something asynchronously
    $scope.loading = false;
};
```

which *immediately* sets loading to `true` and then right back to `false`. You should set loading to `false` from inside the `success` and `error` callbacks instead.

Comment: I think that's originally where I had it, was success, then I looked at it and said to myself what happens if it errors, it will still be displayed so I moved it! This also means the initial loading is incorrect too.